# Should back end server send 503 to the AWS ELB

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, hapi.js

I have a Hapi.js node server. I can configure my app to spit out a 503 as a failsafe if node is running slow (event loop delay crossing the threshold or similar settings). Does AWS ELB in front of my EC2 running this node understand 503 and will it re-route the requests to other nodes under ELB. Is this a good pattern ?

Comment: If you are asking whether ELB will redispatch an in-flight request to a different node if it gets a 503 in response, I believe you will find that it returns the 503 to the client, since it does not have a way of knowing whether the request is idempotent and therefore safe to redispatch.  Is that what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

AWS ELB pings the port that is set in health check and if it does not gets 200 Ok message on that port it marks that node as unhealthy and stops sending traffic to that node.

So if you make that node send 503 on the health check port set in the Load Balancer then the ELB will stop sending traffic to that node.